# google map Displaying text directions with setPanel() issue

Tags: google-maps

I try Google map Displaying text directions with setPanel().  Google's example works on IE9 but  my test page  has an issue on IE9 despite the fact that I copy the same code. Direction arrows in the direction panel don't scroll with the text, they remain fixed. No problem for Chrome. Why ? Thanks. Code is as below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Displaying text directions with <code>setPanel()</code></title>
<style>
  html, body, #map-canvas {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px
  }
  #panel {
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -180px;
    z-index: 5;
    background-color: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    border: 1px solid #999;
  }
</style>
<style>
  #directions-panel {
    height: 100%;
    float: right;
    width: 390px;
    overflow: auto;
  }

  #map-canvas {
    margin-right: 400px;
  }

  #control {
    background: #fff;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 2px rgba(33, 33, 33, 0.4);
    display: none;
  }

  @media print {
    #map-canvas {
      height: 500px;
      margin: 0;
    }

    #directions-panel {
      float: none;
      width: auto;
    }
  }
</style>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false"></script>
<script>
var directionsDisplay;
 var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();

function initialize() {
directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
 var mapOptions = {
zoom: 7,
mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
center: new google.maps.LatLng(41.850033, -87.6500523)
 };
 var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'),
  mapOptions);
   directionsDisplay.setMap(map);
   directionsDisplay.setPanel(document.getElementById('directions-panel'));



    var control = document.getElementById('control');
      control.style.display = 'block';
  map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_CENTER].push(control);
}

function calcRoute() {
  var start = document.getElementById('start').value;
  var end = document.getElementById('end').value;
  var request = {
    origin: start,
    destination: end,
    travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING
  };
  directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
      directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

    </script>
  </head>

<body>
    <div id="control">
      <strong>Start:</strong>
      <select id="start" onchange="calcRoute();">
        <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
        <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
        <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
        <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
        <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
        <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
        <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
        <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
        <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
        <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
        <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
        <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
      </select>
      <strong>End:</strong>
      <select id="end" onchange="calcRoute();">
        <option value="chicago, il">Chicago</option>
        <option value="st louis, mo">St Louis</option>
        <option value="joplin, mo">Joplin, MO</option>
        <option value="oklahoma city, ok">Oklahoma City</option>
        <option value="amarillo, tx">Amarillo</option>
        <option value="gallup, nm">Gallup, NM</option>
        <option value="flagstaff, az">Flagstaff, AZ</option>
        <option value="winona, az">Winona</option>
        <option value="kingman, az">Kingman</option>
        <option value="barstow, ca">Barstow</option>
        <option value="san bernardino, ca">San Bernardino</option>
        <option value="los angeles, ca">Los Angeles</option>
      </select>
    </div>
    <div id="directions-panel"></div>
    <div id="map-canvas"></div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: please post your code (at least the part that is applicable) in your question (not just links).

Comment: None of the versions of IE I have access to has a problem with your test link (at least I don't see what I understand to be the reported problem).

Comment: I see double scroll bar after I select the cities. One for the page , one for the sidebar. When I scroll the page , little direction icons on the sidebar are fixed and continue to be seen towards the end of the page . It display all the icons at one time even the ones which  must be diplayed after the scroll.

Comment: I don't see that in IE8 (don't have access to IE9 ATM).

Answer (score 2):

I've had the same issue.  I was finally able to work around it by overriding the css style for the arrow icon and it's container.  Add the following style defintions to your page, after the google api script is loaded:

```
    /* Override Google Maps Icon style */
    .adp-substep .adp-stepicon .adp-maneuver {
        position: static;
    }

    /* Override Google Maps Icon Container style */
    .adp-substep .adp-stepicon{
        position: static;
    }
```

This overrides the *position: absolute* that the google api automatically uses on those the classes.  Still not sure why absolute sometimes acts like fixed, but this override worked for me.